# Code First Mapping and Repositories

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, class, design-patterns

I am learning the repository pattern and entity framework. I have a question regarding how to map my classes with EF 6 Code First (Existing Db). I know there a lot of questions about this (and I've readed maany of them) but still it's hard for me to understand something, which appears to be "logic" but it's getting me crazy (maybe I have readed too many different opinions...)

#### Problem (Example)

A table `Processes` which stores different processes like offer, receipt, order etc.. One of the columns of the table is `AddDate` which represents when this process was added to the DB.

Now I want to write a library to access this DB to use it in different apps, since it's the *core* Db in the company.

In the library I want to expose for example a `ProcessRepository` with a method `GetByAddDateRange` which returns the processes added after, before or in a given time range.

#### Question

So, now EF with CodeFirst to an existing DB first generates for me a class for every table with a property for every field. So I have a class `Process` (from now `ProcessEntity)` with a property `AddDate`.

Now in my "domain model", the classes that I want to use in my businnes logic etc, I want to have a class `Process` (from now `ProcessDomain)` but this should not have an `AddDate` property, since it's not important for the "object" or is part of its "properties".

So now how should I do then if I want to get `ProcessDomains` from my `ProcessRepository` using this AddDate as condition?

1. If I use directly `ProcessEntity` as "domain model" (class generated by EF) and if I understand it right, I have to have a property called `AddDate` since I will need it in my repo when doing sth like `Return _dbContext.Set(Of Process).Where(Func(s)s.AddDate>addDate)` or not?
2. I could (like I've read) have a class `ProcessEntity` and `ProcessDomain` and map manually between them in my repository. If I understand it right the repo should return the expected type for the layer above, in this case should return my domainModel class.

#### Do I understand it?

So for me the first option appears just in close to all scenarios useless, since you have to have specific properties in your classes.  so it doesn't matter how I try to look at the problem I always see the need to map manually when using an existing db.

Maybe I am missing sth or understanding sth wrong, so please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EF entities need to have properties for all the database columns you want to use, which includes those you want to filter by. This means that your EF class that corresponds to that table must have that `AddDate` property. If you want a class that doesn't have that property then you need to define another class.

Many developers/teams will do that anyway. We do mostly ASP.NET MVC work in my office and we have an EF model that corresponds to the database and repositories that return types from that, then we have a service layer that maps those EF entities to data transfer objects (DTOs).  The DTOs may map 100% to a corresponding entity but they may also be missing some properties and/or have extra properties. There may also be DTOs that don't correspond to a single entity.  We usually use web services between app and database so the DTOs are as efficient as they can be for reduced data transfer.

We have our own tool to generate the DTOs based on the EF model.  We will then adjust the generated code as required.  If we need to add members, we generally do so in a partial class, so future regeneration doesn't affect that code.  If we need to remove members then we have no choice but to edit the generated code.  We also use AutoMapper to map data between EF entities and DTOs and vice versa.

Comment: so you have in your service layer (for example) a GetByAddDate method, which calls the GetByAddDate method in your repo and maps the results to DTOs or how do you do it?

Comment: In our case, repositories are about data access only.  All business logic, e.g. filtering, is applied in the service layer. Our DAL includes a unit of work that exposes the repositories. A service instantiates the UoW and gets the appropriate repository(ies) from it, then calls appropriate LINQ to Entities methods so filter or whatever. We're going to look at the possibility of doing away with the UoW soon but the principle won't change.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Create DTOs that have what you actually want. Map between the entities and the DTOs when reading/writing. (The mapping is tedious and error prone. AutoMapper helps a lot.)

Option 2:

Use attributes such as DataContract/DataMember on your entities to control what fields are serialized and which are ignored.

Still error prone because entities are full of collections that aren't necessarily populated.

Option 3:

Use a different ORM. Tortuga Chain is designed specifically for working with DTOs and ViewModels without the need to map them to entities.

https://docevaad.github.io/Chain/Introduction.htm